# Merge/Mux multiple mp4 video files on Android

Tags: java, android, mediamuxer, mediaextractor

I have a series of mp4 files saved on the device that need to be merged together to make a single mp4 file.

video_p1.mp4 video_p2.mp4 video_p3.mp4 > video.mp4

The solutions I have researched such as the mp4parser framework use deprecated code.

The best solution I could find is using a MediaMuxer and MediaExtractor.

The code runs but my videos are not merged (only the content in video_p1.mp4 is displayed and it is in landscape orientation, not portrait).

Can anyone help me sort this out?

```
    public static boolean concatenateFiles(File dst, File... sources) {
    if ((sources == null) || (sources.length == 0)) {
        return false;
    }

    boolean result;
    MediaExtractor extractor = null;
    MediaMuxer muxer = null;
    try {
        // Set up MediaMuxer for the destination.
        muxer = new MediaMuxer(dst.getPath(), MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

        // Copy the samples from MediaExtractor to MediaMuxer.
        boolean sawEOS = false;
        //int bufferSize = MAX_SAMPLE_SIZE;
        int bufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        int frameCount = 0;
        int offset = 100;

        ByteBuffer dstBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

        long timeOffsetUs = 0;
        int dstTrackIndex = -1;

        for (int fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < sources.length; fileIndex++) {
            int numberOfSamplesInSource = getNumberOfSamples(sources[fileIndex]);

            // Set up MediaExtractor to read from the source.
            extractor = new MediaExtractor();
            extractor.setDataSource(sources[fileIndex].getPath());

            // Set up the tracks.
            SparseIntArray indexMap = new SparseIntArray(extractor.getTrackCount());
            for (int i = 0; i < extractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
                extractor.selectTrack(i);
                MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
                if (dstTrackIndex < 0) {
                    dstTrackIndex = muxer.addTrack(format);
                    muxer.start();
                }
                indexMap.put(i, dstTrackIndex);
            }

            long lastPresentationTimeUs = 0;
            int currentSample = 0;

            while (!sawEOS) {
                bufferInfo.offset = offset;
                bufferInfo.size = extractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, offset);

                if (bufferInfo.size < 0) {
                    sawEOS = true;
                    bufferInfo.size = 0;
                    timeOffsetUs += (lastPresentationTimeUs + 0);
                }
                else {
                    lastPresentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
                    bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime() + timeOffsetUs;
                    bufferInfo.flags = extractor.getSampleFlags();
                    int trackIndex = extractor.getSampleTrackIndex();

                    if ((currentSample < numberOfSamplesInSource) || (fileIndex == sources.length - 1)) {
                        muxer.writeSampleData(indexMap.get(trackIndex), dstBuf, bufferInfo);
                    }
                    extractor.advance();

                    frameCount++;
                    currentSample++;
                    Log.d("tag2", "Frame (" + frameCount + ") " +
                                "PresentationTimeUs:" + bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +
                                " Flags:" + bufferInfo.flags +
                                " TrackIndex:" + trackIndex +
                                " Size(KB) " + bufferInfo.size / 1024);

                }
            }
            extractor.release();
            extractor = null;
        }

        result = true;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        result = false;
    }
    finally {
        if (extractor != null) {
            extractor.release();
        }
        if (muxer != null) {
            muxer.stop();
            muxer.release();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static int getNumberOfSamples(File src) {
    MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
    int result;
    try {
        extractor.setDataSource(src.getPath());
        extractor.selectTrack(0);

        result = 0;
        while (extractor.advance()) {
            result ++;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        result = -1;
    }
    finally {
        extractor.release();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this library for muxing videos: [ffmpeg-android-java](https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android-java)

**gradle dependency:**

```
implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
```

Here's how I use it in my project to mux video and audio in kotlin: [VideoAudioMuxer](https://github.com/hikikomoriphoenix/Beedio/blob/develop-beedio/base/src/main/java/marabillas/loremar/beedio/base/media/VideoAudioMuxer.kt)
So basically it works like the ffmpeg in terminal but you're inputing your command to a method as an array of strings along with a listener.

```
fmpeg.execute(arrayOf("-i", videoPath, "-i", audioPath, "$targetPath.mp4"), object : ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
```

You'll have to search how to merge videos in ffmpeg and convert the commands into array of strings for the argument you need.

You could probably do almost anything, since ffmpeg is a very powerful tool.